# How we can create Material UI Switch Group component with yup and formik

Tags: formik, yup, formik-material-ui

There is no support for SwitchGroup as there is for RadioGroup from Material UI, I am trying to create SwitchGroup to show an error in formik form through yup. But how can we achieve that?

from what I get to understand from this [article](https://dev.to/brad_beggs/dynamically-create-toggle-switch-list-for-attendance-w-hooks-materialui-58oi) switch group can be created but how can we add validation to it from yup/ formik?

code sandbox link from the form:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-haze-qiymy?from-embed

Comment: I have edited your code according to formik https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-water-pfsz38?file=/src/components/Attending.tsx. You can get values in `handleSubmit` function. Also, what kind of error and validation you want to show?

Comment: validation that if all the switches are in false state, it should through error that one switch as true is required through Yup